# How to validate multiple value with single field in laravel validation

Tags: laravel, validation

I have array of id and i want to validate each id with database table using laravel validator so how can i validate multiple id

My code like this

```
$idArray = [10,15,16]; // I have tree routine_schedule table id 
$validatior = Validator::make(array("id"=>$idArray), ["id"=>"required|exists:routine_schedule,id"]);
if ($validatior->passes()){
    exit('valid');
}else{
    exit('invalid');
}
```

I wan to validate each and every id is exist in routine_schedule table? so how can i validate this array id's

Comment: Your code should work. what is the error?

Comment: No it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public function rules($idArray)
{
  $rules = [];

  foreach($idArray as $key => $val)
  {
    $rules[$key] = 'required|exists:routine_schedule,id';
  }

  return $rules;
}

$validatior = Validator::make($idArray, rules($idArray));
```