# Laravel Array Validation

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, validation

```
$rules = [
            'user_id'           => 'required|exists:users,id',
            'preparat_id'       => 'required|exists:preparats,id',
            'zoom'              => 'required|numeric',
            'comment'           => '',
            'type'              => 'in:' . Annotation::ANN_RECTANGLE . ',' . Annotation::ANN_CIRCLE . ',' . Annotation::ANN_POLYGON . ',' . Annotation::ANN_PIN,
            'point_x'           => 'array|required|numeric',
            'point_y'           => 'array|required|numeric',
        ];

        $this->validate($request, $rules);
```

`point_x` and `point_y` is an array input.

My rule is :

`point_x` and `point_y` must be exist.

How I send data :

- point_x[0] = 123;
- point_y[0] = 123;

**TRUE**

---

- point_x[0] = 123;
- point_y[0] = 123;
- point_x[1] = 123;
- point_y[1] = 123;
- point_x[2] = 123;
- point_y[2] = 123;

**TRUE**

---

point_x[0] = 123;
point_y[0] = "SO";

**WRONG**

---

point_y[0] = 123;

**WRONG**

---

- point_x[0] = 123;
- point_y[0] = 123;
- point_x[1] = 123;
- point_y[1] = "Taadaa";
- point_x[2] = 123;
- point_y[2] = 123;

**WRONG**

My Laravel version is 5.4

How should I write a rule for check like above. I tried to array parameter, but it does not work.

Comment: I solved a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715505/how-to-validate-multiple-value-with-single-field-in-laravel-validation/44715782#44715782

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following rules for arrays `point_x` and `point_y` only,

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'point_x' => 'required',
    'point_y' => 'required',
    'point_x.*' => 'numeric',
    'point_y.*' => 'numeric',
], 
     $messages = [

     ]
);
```

See docs [Array Input Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#validating-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

```
  public function rules($array)
    {
      $rules = [  
            'user_id'           => 'required|exists:users,id',
            'preparat_id'       => 'required|exists:preparats,id',
            'zoom'              => 'required|numeric',
            'comment'           => '',
            'type'              => 'in:' . Annotation::ANN_RECTANGLE . ',' . Annotation::ANN_CIRCLE . ',' . Annotation::ANN_POLYGON . ',' . Annotation::ANN_PIN,];

      foreach($array as $key => $val)
      {
        $rules[$key] = 'required|numeric';
      }
      return $rules;
    }
```